# What is meant by symptom based monitoring and cause based monitoring?

Tags: performance, devops, monitoring, sre

In SRE context, what is meant by symptom and cause-based monitoring? why it is so important? And which tools are used for these kinds of monitoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Symptoms Versus Causes**
>
> ---
>
> Your monitoring system should address two questions: what’s broken,
> and why?
>
> The "what’s broken" indicates the symptom; the "why" indicates a
> (possibly intermediate) cause. Table below lists some hypothetical
> symptoms and corresponding causes.
>
> "What" versus "why" is one of the most important distinctions in
> writing good monitoring with maximum signal and minimum noise.

### Example

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                        Symptom                         |                                                      Cause                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| I’m serving HTTP 500s or 404s                          | Database servers are refusing connections                                                                       |
|--------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| My responses are slow                                  | CPUs are overloaded by a bogosort, or an Ethernet cable is crimped under a rack, visible as partial packet loss |
|--------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Users in Antarctica aren’t receiving animated cat GIFs | Your Content Distribution Network hates scientists and felines, and thus blacklisted some client IPs            |
|--------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Private content is world-readable                      | A new software push caused ACLs to be forgotten and allowed all requests                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[Source](https://landing.google.com/sre/sre-book/chapters/monitoring-distributed-systems)

Tools used for monitoring depends on your platform, what and how you want to monitor. For example, [Azure Monitor](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/monitor/) is for the applications and infrastructure hosted in Azure, [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch) for those in AWS, and so the list goes on.